# MySQL: reasoning in a chain

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a large table that contains words from text files (`offset_1` is simply `offset` - 1):

```
file  offset offset_1 word
----  ------ -------- ----
1.txt   1       0     I
1.txt   2       1     have
1.txt   3       2     a
1.txt   4       3     large
1.txt   5       4     table
1.txt   6       5     that
1.txt   7       6     contains
```

I want to find pairs of words at a given distance or less. For example, "a" and "table" with at most 1 word in between.

What I do now is (in MySQL):

```
SELECT t1.offset, t3.offset
FROM t as t1 JOIN t as t2 JOIN t as t3
ON t2.file = t1.file AND t3.file = t1.file AND 
(
     (t1.offset = t2.offset_1 AND t2.offset = t3.offset_1) # "a large table"
  OR (t1.offset = t3.offset_1 AND t2.offset = 1)           # "a table"
)
WHERE t1.word = 'a' AND t3.word = 'table'
```

but this never terminates (the table is large).

If I remove any one of the two conditions under OR, it works and correctly finds "a large table" or "a table", respectively.

What is the correct way?

Comment: I suggest you start with a smaller table. Get your query working on that, then look at performance.

Comment: I'm not sure what the _"t2.offset = 1"_ is for - do you need "I" in there somewhere too.

Comment: @PaulF I believe `t2` should be constraint somehow not to multiply the result. Otherwise I would get a whole bunch of identical results, one per each row of t2, since it is `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: Also I didn't understand why you needed three joins. Where in the query are you checking for a gap of at most one word - which is in my second answer.

Comment: @PaulF I look for three words: "a", some `X` that goes after "a", and "table" that goes after `X`. This does work and gives a gap of exactly 1. With only two tables I get the gap of 0. So my plan was to OR these two cases: using the middle word (`t2`) or ignoring it. But I suspect JOIN cannot be used in this way, can it?

Comment: See comments to my answer below regarding not needing t2.

Comment: MySQL doesn't have window functions like `LEAD`, so any set-based solution for MySQL would involve self-join => `O(n*n)` => slow. Use cursor, it will be `O(n)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest splitting this into two queries, using `union all`.  SOmething like this:

```
SELECT t1.offset, t3.offset
FROM t t1 JOIN
     t t2
     ON t2.file = t1.file AND t1.offset = t2.offset_1
WHERE t1.word = 'a' AND t2.word = 'table'
UNION ALL
SELECT t1.offset, t3.offset
FROM t t1 JOIN
     t t2
     ON t2.file = t1.file AND t1.offset = t2.offset_1 JOIN
     t t3
     ON t3.file = t2.file and t2.offset = t3.offset_1
WHERE t1.word = 'a' AND t3.word = 'table';
```

`OR` in `JOIN` conditions often has a bad impact on performance.  Sometimes splitting the logic into multiple subqueries can be a big win

Comment: Thank you! I will give it a try and will let you know.

Comment: This worked for me. I was reluctant to try it because I believed that UNION of N almost identical queries would be N times slower. Surprisingly, it is almost as fast as one query (because of caching I believe), Only with some 30-50 copies I start noticing significant delay.

Comment: Actually what worked for me was a simpler expression: `... t2.offset = t1.offset + 1 ... UNION ALL ... t2.offset = t1.offset + 2 ... UNION ALL ... t2.offset = t1.offset + 3 ...` to find pairs at distance from 1 to N. I even did not use the field `offset_1`, and I used only two tables `t1` and `t2` in JOIN in each SELECT, with the only difference of `+ i` in the SELECTs.

Answer (score 1):

Would this work

```
SELECT t1.offset, t2.offset
FROM t as t1 
JOIN t as t2 ON t2.file = t1.file 
WHERE t1.word = 'a' AND t2.word = 'table'
AND (t2.offset - t1.offset) <= 2
```

Comment: I tried something like this, but it was extremely slow, I guess because indexes could not be used so SQL had to try all combinations to see which ones would be < 2.

Comment: Try finding out what the execution plan is (run query with "EXPLAIN " in front of it) - that will show if it using the indexes as expected.

Comment: Can you modify the table to use an integer to identify the file - the join would then be quicker than doing string comparisons.

Comment: Yes, normalization will be the next step. But for now the question is why any of the two options under OR work OK but together they hang. Normalization will not solve this.

Comment: I think it is because you have a large table & making two joins - so potentially (number of records) cubed. If you do the maths on the complicated expression you will see that the first part equates to (t3.offset - t1.offset) = 2 (t2 is not involved here) & the second part to (((t3.offset - t1.offset) = 1)  AND (t2.offset = 1)). The t2 check is just to limit the size of join - but is not needed, so that join can be removed - leaving the query above.

Comment: Yes, right, in theory (with a small table) your solution would work. But I believe this query cannot use indexes, so in a large table it will have a prohibitive O(n^2) complexity. I tried a similar solution and it was too slow. My question is not about how to find the answer, but how to find it efficiently.

Comment: I would expect adding a second join would reduce efficiency. You could check the query plan for each option with EXPLAIN.

Comment: I found that a query with `<` is prohibitively show when it deals with large sets; I believe this is because it cannot use indexing. Surprizingly, a query with `t2.offset = t1.offset + 123` works (almost?) as fast as `t2.offset_1 = t1.offset`; I believe MySQL does use index with `=` but not with `<`. The other answer (with `=` and UNION) did work for me.

Comment: Anyway, your answer will be useful for smaller tables. Upvoting.